# Object reference not set to an object. (SQLEditors)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2 on my local machine, Its working fine. But when I an connecting to Server on internet on which SQL Server 2012 is loaded, I am able to connect but not able to save Views. When I am saving the View I am Getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an object. (SQLEditors).

If any one has got the solution, Please help me.

Comment: Can you show us the code that gving the error?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the query designer in SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 R2 is incompatible with SQL Server 2012.

You have two options:

- When saving the view, issue an `ALTER VIEW` statement, instead of using the designer.
- Install SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2012 on your local machine.

Comment: I am Sorry to inform you that I am using SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 R2 & I don't have SQL Server 2012

Comment: Just download [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). It is a free download, and you can just install Management Studio alone, without the database engine, etc.

Comment: Which File shall I download I am using Windows-8 (32 bit)

Comment: ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

Comment: Out of these files which file shall I download , I am using Windows-8 (32 bit)
ENU\x64\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe

ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe

ENU\x64\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe

ENU\x64\SqlLocalDB.MSI

ENU\x64\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe


ENU\x86\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe


ENU\x86\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe


ENU\x86\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe


ENU\x86\SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU.exe


ENU\x86\SqlLocaLDB.MSI


ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

Comment: I already answered that, but here we go again: ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

Comment: Thanks, I am downloading the file. I will let you no the result after Installation.

Comment: No problem. Please consider marking my post as the answer to your question, so that others can see that it solved your problem.